# CSS attribute selector of subclass

Tags: html, css

just a curiosity.

If i have CSS rules like this:

```
.section{width:100%;min-height:200px;}
.section.container-1{background:blue;}
.section.container-2{background:red;}
.section.container-3{background:orange;}
```

is it possible to use the

> css attribute selector

so that i can write something like:

```
.section.[class*='container-'] h1{color:white}
```

Just to clarify:

- I will have a structure where `.section` is the common class to all the DIVs (width and height)
- All the containers inside `.section` will have different style (background color)
- All the `H1` inside `.container-n` will have the same style. (color, font etc)

here's an example HTML code to make it more clear:

```
<div class="section container-1"><h1></h1><!--Will display blue background and white text --></div>
<div class="section container-2"><h1></h1><!--Will display red background and white text --></div>
<div class="section container-3"><h1></h1> <!--Will display orange background and white text --></div>
```

I know that i can do it in different ways, and i already know how to do it, i just wonder if something like above could be possible or not.

thanks

Comment: Best way to find out would be to try it.

Comment: Yes it is like so `.section[class*='container-']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Just remove the period prefixing the attribute selector.

```
.section.[class*='container-'] h1
/*      ^ remove that.. it's an attribute selector, not a class. */
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk1Lnwff/)